# Is it possible to listen to different ports in the same domain name?

Tags: linux, https, port, hosting

I am a newbie in server hosting and i have the code source of several applications that i can run on localhost and i want to host them in the same website

So let's say that i am running the first one which is written with JavaScript frameworks in port 8080: https://localhost:8080
and the second one which is written in Java is running in port 3000; https://localhost:3000

What i want to do is to host the first one as www.example.com/first and the second one as  www.example.com/second, is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to use something like [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for Apache's httpd or [`proxy_pass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for nginx.